# Avoid to use ALooper

Tags: android, android-ndk, native-activity

Is it possible to avoid using ALooper in NativeActivity?

I'm writing a native activity without app glue and I want to skip the ALooper thing, I can implement something like that, that is more specific for my case, but it is important for me to not loose any functionality like: Motion, Input, Sensor, ... .

As far as I can see this ALooper thing can be easily removed, but I'm not completely sure about it, specially for future needs.

Comment: how do you want to call `ASensorManager_createEventQueue` without `ALooper`?

Comment: you can loop over it and check it in every loop.

Comment: I was thinking about ASensorEventQueue_getEvents, but now, I see, there is no other way to create ASensorEventQueue

Comment: so @pskink write your answer. I'll accept it.

Comment: I was wondering to if I could get rid of it, it is really ugly to use. Simply loop over 'AInputQueue_getEvent' should also work no ? Would be much clearer code, but just saw the issue with the sensor events .. sad. But if we dont use sensors it wouldnt be an issue...